# zsh: Command substitution and proper quoting

Tags: zsh

I have a script `P` which accepts file names as parameters:

```
P file1 file2 file3 ....
```

I also have a script `G` which generates a (typically short list) of file names, one file name per line. In a master script which I would like to write in *zsh*, I want to use `G` to generate the file names to be processed by `P`. The naive attempt goes like this:

```
P $(G)
```

This works nearly well, only that I'm living in a world where malicious people enjoy creating files with embedded spaces. If `G` would generate the list of files like this:

```
one_file 
a file with spaces
```

`P` would be called as

```
P one_file a file with spaces
```

instead of

```
P 'one_file' 'a file with spaces'
```

One obvious solution would be to glue `G` and `P` together not by command substitution, but by a small program in some language (Ruby, Perl, Python, Algol68,....), which does an exec of `P` and passes the parameters to a read from stdin.

This would be trivial to write and could even be made reusable. However, I wonder, whether *zsh* with its grabbag of goodies would not have a solution for this problem builtin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with:

```
P ${(f)"$(G)"}
```

which will call `P` as

```
P 'one_file' 'a file with spaces'
```

if the output of `G` is

```
one_file
a file with spaces
```

**Explanation:**

The double quotes around `$(G)` tell *zsh* to take the output of `G` as one word (in the shell sense of the word word).

So just calling

```
P "$(G)"
```

would be equivaent of

```
P 'one_file
a file with spaces'
```

This is where the *Parameter Expansion Flag* `f` comes into play. `${(f)SOMEVAR}` tells *zsh* to split `$SOMEVAR` into words at newlines. Instead of a parameter (like `SOMEVAR`) one can also use a command substitution (here `$(G)`) inside `${...}` type parmeter expressions, which leads to the the command `P ${(f)"$(G)"}`.