# zsh: command substitution, proper quoting and backslash (again)

Tags: zsh

(Note: This is a successor question to my posting [zsh: Command substitution and proper quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028828/zsh-command-substitution-and-proper-quoting) , but now with an additional complication).

I have a function _iwpath_helper, which outputs to stdout a path, which possibly contains spaces. For the sake of this discussion, let's assume that _iwpath_helper always returns a constant text, for instance

```
function _iwpath_helper
{
    echo "home/rovf/my directory with spaces"
}
```

I also have a function quote_stripped expects one parameter and if this parameter is surrounded by quotes, it removes them and returns the remaining text. If the parameter is not surrounded by quotes, it returns it unchanged. Here is its definition:

```
function quote_stripped 
{
    echo ${1//[\"\']/}
}
```

Now I combine both functions in the following way:

```
target=$(quote_stripped "${(q)$(_iwpath_helper)}")
```

(Of course, 'quote_stripped' would be unnecessary in this toy example, because _iwpath_helper doesn't return a quote-delimited path here, but in the real application, it sometimes does).

The problem now is that the variable target contains a **real** backslash character, i.e. if I do a

```
echo +++$target+++
```

I see

```
+++home/rovf/my\ directory\ with\ spaces
```

and if I try to

```
cd $target
```

I get on my system the error message, that the directory

```
home/rovf/my/ directory/ with/ spaces
```

would not exist.

(In case you are wondering where the forward slashes come from: I'm running on Cygwin, and I guess that the cd command just interprets backslashes as forward slashes in this case, to accomodate better for the Windows environment).

I guess the backslashes, which physically appear in the variable *target* are caused by the (q) expansion flag which I apply to $(_iwpath_helper). My problem is now that I can not simply drop the (q), because without it, the function quote_stripped would get on parameter $1 only the first part of the string, up to the first space (*/home/rovf/my*).

How can I write this correctly?

Comment: I think you need a clearer example where quoting and unquoting is necessary. The `_iwpath_helper` function you show would work fine with simply `target=$(_iwpath_helper); cd $target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chepner was right: The way I tried to unquote the string was silly (I was thinking too much in a "Bourne Shell way"), and I should have used the (Q) flag.

Here is my solution:

```
target="${(Q)$(_iwpath_helper)}"
```

No need for the quote_stripped function anymore....

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to avoid trying to strip quotes manually, and use the `(Q)` expansion flag. Compare:

```
% v="a b c d"
% echo "$v"
a b c d
% echo "${(q)v}"
a\ b\ c\ d
% echo "${(Q)${(q)v}}"
a b c d
```